# Related problems with ladder

Tags: applications

A ladder **AB** of length **2a** and weight **w** is inclined to a smooth horizontal ground(**A**) at an angle **$\theta$** and rests against a smooth vertical wall(**B**). The centre of gravity **G** of the ladder is $\frac{3}{8}$ of the way up . The middle of the ladder, **O**,is tied to a point in the vertical wall by a horizontal rope of length ***l***. The reactions at **A** and **B** are **R** and **S** respectively.
Show that tension in the rope is $\frac{3wl}{4\sqrt{a^2-l^2}}$.

I have obtained $\cos(\theta)$=$\frac{l}{a}$ ; $\sin(\theta)$= $\frac{\sqrt{a^2-l^2}}{a}$ ; $\tan(\theta)$ = $\frac{\sqrt{a^2-l^2}}{l}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**:

You do not need any Lami's theorem, nor any m-n theorem of trigonometry. It's just $$F_{net} = 0$$

and

$$\tau_{net} = 0$$

Since the rod is in equilibrium, the forces and torques cancel out. The horizontal forces are $T$ and $R$ (anti parallel) and the vertical ones are $W$ and $S$. Now, using the first equation you get:
$$ R = T$$
and $$ W = S $$

The second equation over here isn't of any consequence, so forget it.

Now, balance the torques. Since we are only interested in $T$, we'd be making our jobs easy by eliminating $S$ - simply consider the torque about point $B$. We are justified in doing so as our rod is in equilibrium.

Balancing the torques gives you the answer.

**MORE HINT**: (I am basically throwing off the answer with this).

The anti-clockwise torques are:

1. $\displaystyle (W\cos\theta)\cdot\Big(\frac3 4a\Big)$
2. $\displaystyle (T\cos(\pi/2 -\theta))\cdot (a)$

The only clock-wise torque is:

1. $\displaystyle (R\cos(\pi/2 - \theta))\cdot(2a)$